# Airbase-ng doesn't hide SSID nor change the MAC?

Tags: mac-address, aircrack-ng

I'm trying to set up a beacon that sends a custom MAC address, with no ssid or other features.

The command I'm using is;

```
airbase-ng -A -a 02:47:4c:61:7a:75 --hidden -c 11 wlan1
```

My problem is that the `--hidden` argument doesn't do anything, since the network still has the "default" ssid, and the `-a` argument doesn't overwrite the random MAC associated in ad-hoc mode.

My purpose here is to be able to beacon a custom MAC address to nearby phones without the network showing up in the WIFI list.

Comment: The documentation might have your answer: https://svn.aircrack-ng.org/trunk/manpages/airbase-ng.8

Comment: "In ad-hoc mode airbase-ng also sends beacons"